# My webiste has million of pages with /?=v"ex".html

Tags: redirect, cms, hacked, spam

I checked Google Search console and i found 1.3M pages with URLS/v?="dhshd1".html
all the pages are indexed in google and not appearing in dashboard and redircts to a page like my home page.
ex: https://sawyancom.com/?v=47e5dceea208205.html
buy my site  is sawynaocom.com